# Required message for Unmapped field?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an unmapped field in asp.net MVC3. I want to display required message for this field but i can't. How can i display required messsage for unmapped fields? Is it possible ?

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email alanı girilmelidir.")]
        public string FirstEMail
        {
            get
            {
                return first_email;
            }
            set
            {
                first_email = value;
            }
        }
```

DAL:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AbsKontak>().Ignore(p => p.FirstEMail);
```

View:

```
Html.LabelFor(p => p.FirstEMail)
Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.FirstEMail, new { class = "medium", disabled = "disabled", id = "txtFirstTel" })
Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.FirstEMail)
```

Comment: Yes. that's 2 different concerns. one is `validation` and the other is `persistence`.

Comment: Can you explain how can i do for this example ?

Comment: How does your View look like?

Comment: Html.LabelFor(p => p.FirstTelefon)
        Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.FirstTelefon, new { class = "medium", disabled = "disabled", id = "txtFirstTel" })
        Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.FirstTelefon)

Comment: Same for `FirstEMail` (the field with `[Required]`)?

Comment: Sorry, i have made a mistake, FirstEmail and FirstTelefon same fields

Comment: Why is the field `disabled`?

Comment: because this field element at IList<Email>. One user can have multiple email adress. if you want to describe any user you must have firstMail. this field is neccessary for this.

Answer (score -1):

Is this your requirement, Please let me know if Iam wrong

**Model:**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="FirstEMail is required")]
 public string FirstEMail{get;set;}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ValidatingFormMessages()
  {
      UserEmail objModel = new UserEmail();
      objModel.FirstEMail = "xxx@yy.com";
      return View(objModel);
  }
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Index(UserEmail coll)
  {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          return RedirectToAction("yourActionName", "YourControllerName");
      }
      return View();
  }
```

**View:**

```
@{Html.BeginForm();}
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstEMail)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstEMail)
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
@{Html.EndForm();}
```